Update table with data from itself
How can I update empty datetime columns with the corresponding date time when the transmitted_profile_fk matches? Could you provide a straightforward SQL query for this task?
See screenshot for table structure:


it would be nice if you provided sample data in the consumable format

Update to the max date of the same column value? A simplified version and possible solution of your use case here: https://dbfiddle.uk/qwi_fQ6q I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after because your description is vague.

Just a minor twist on Jonas's answer  https://dbfiddle.uk/2pAUV5f6

Please don't use images for data, use table markdown

See example.
Datetime column will be updated by subquery result.
If subquery result is null, null will be update by null.
update test
  set datetime=(select max(datetime) from test t2 
                where t2.transmitted_profile_fk=test.transmitted_profile_fk)
where test.datetime is null;

With test data



id
transmitted_profile_fk
datetime




1
617c1fee-1bf1-441b-a3c9-51c592edce46
2024-04-12 22:43:45.913


2
617c1fee-1bf1-441b-a3c9-51c592edce46
null


3
ff2c9ff2-72ac-484e-9bfb-7e4ef298cd72
2024-04-12 22:44:24.883


4
527d9571-1b80-4ccb-bb1f-c2de4cb20a5a
null



2 rows affected




id
transmitted_profile_fk
datetime




1
617c1fee-1bf1-441b-a3c9-51c592edce46
2024-04-12 22:43:45.913


2
617c1fee-1bf1-441b-a3c9-51c592edce46
2024-04-12 22:43:45.913


3
ff2c9ff2-72ac-484e-9bfb-7e4ef298cd72
2024-04-12 22:44:24.883


4
527d9571-1b80-4ccb-bb1f-c2de4cb20a5a
null



Another example
update test
  set datetime=upd.dttm
from (select transmitted_profile_fk,max(datetime) dttm from test t2
      group by transmitted_profile_fk
     ) upd
where test.transmitted_profile_fk=upd.transmitted_profile_fk
  and test.datetime is null and upd.dttm is not null;

output is
1 rows affected

There we chek max(datetime) is not null to avoid unnecessary updates.

This should do the trick
It gets all DateTimes that are not null, gets the first element and updates the DateTime where the transmitted_profile_fk is the same as the one where the DateTime is not null
At the end it deletes the row from our local variable.
This continues as long as there are rows in the local variable
Note that you need to insert your TABLE_NAME
declare @local TABLE(ID int, transmitted_profile_fk varchar(100), "DateTime" DateTime)
INSERT INTO @local select ID, transmitted_profile_fk, "DateTime" from { TABLE_NAME } where "DateTime" is not null

while (select count(ID) from @local) > 0
begin
    declare @id int
    declare @transmitted_profile_fk varchar(100)
    declare @DateTime DateTime

    select TOP 1 @id = ID, @transmitted_profile_fk = transmitted_profile_fk, @DateTime = "DateTime" from @local

    update { TABLE_NAME } set "DateTime" = @DateTime where transmitted_profile_fk = @transmitted_profile_fk
    delete from @local where ID = @id
end


This is a most inefficient technique that unnecessarily uses a temporary table and a while loop, when the entire operation can be done using a set-based operation.

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        *
        , New_POST_TIME = ISNULL(POST_TIME, FIRST_VALUE(POST_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY TRANSMITTED_PROFILE_FK ORDER BY POST_TIME DESC))
    FROM @Example
    ORDER BY ID
)

UPDATE CTE
SET POST_TIME = New_POST_TIME

I changed the name of the 'DateTime' column to 'Post Time'

A good answer contains an explanation
